# Generate parameter placeholder using spring SpEL

Tags: java, spring

I need to replace a set of values which passes through array to a formatted string. See below example,

```
String value="abc {0} def {1} ghi {2}";

String[] replacingValue={"T1","T2","T3"};

//{i} values should be replaced with T1,T2...etc.

String result="abc T1 def T2 ghi T3";
```

Is there anyway we can do this using Spring SpEL?

Comment: Is there a specific need for the SPEL? Can't you use `MessageFormat.format`

Comment: No requirement is to use SpEL. Previously I tried that approach. Did get through. If you have sample code with MessageFormat.format please post it for the knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
String value = "abc {0} def {1} ghi {2}";

String[] replacingValue = { "T1", "T2", "T3" };

// {i} values should be replaced with T1,T2...etc.

String result = MessageFormat.format(value, replacingValue);

System.out.println(result);
```